# Is there a way to make a two-way MultiBinding only use a converter in a single direction?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom MultiValue Converter to perform a bit of logic while MultiBinding to a TextBox; however I do not want to use the convertBack since the binding value does not have a compile-time type and the default conversion works perfectly. Is this possible or do I have to somehow replicate the functionailty of one of the internal default converters?

Diagram:

```
values --> Convert() --> TextBox
values <---------------- TextBox
```

Thank you.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I am using a MultiValueConverter and MultiBinding which seems to bypass the default converter.

Edit: To expand on the reasoning behind this: I have two objects A & B (of the same type) that I want to edit simultaneously in a TextBox. In the Convert method, I check if they are the same value and either display the value or a default. If the user changes the value in the TextBox, I want the same value to be sent back to both A & B.

**Edit: I have solved the issue in a roundabout fashion - please see my response below. If you have a better solution I would still appreciate hearing it. Thanks again for your time and help.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I just figured out a solution... Thanks to everyone for posting suggestions.

It turns out that if you create a pass-through ValueConverter (as in just return value for both Convert and ConvertBack), and add it to the sub-Bindings of the MultiBinding, that the default conversions will happen as expected. What must be happening is that the MultiBinding in general bypasses the defaultConverter of the sub-Bindings.

Comment: Wow this is interesting. I never experimented with how converters on each of the sub-bindings would behave. I'll have to try that sometime.

Answer (score 6):

Just return value in convertback

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return YourLogic(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using a MultiValueConverter / MultiBinding which seems to bypass the 'default'converter when I simply return the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to bypass the converter.

As @ArsenMkrt explained, you'll have to pass the original values through the converter.

For a MultiBinding this is tough because you have to be able to turn 1 value into N. You will probably have to store information in the converter on the first pass to help you do this. I have rarely used two-way MultiBindings largely because it is hard to convert back from a single value to many values.

There's still a missing piece here. Why would you want to pass the default value through a MultiBinding? That's impossible. A MultiBinding always needs a converter because you are folding multiple values into one and then expanding one value into many.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an edit explaining my reasoning. In my testing I returned an array of the ConvertBack value but the defaultConversion is not performed.

Comment: No need for a converter if you use `StringFormat`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
MyType Default { get; set; }

public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    // compare values, return value if equal or default
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(value, targetTypes.Length).ToArray();
}
```

The return function passes the value back to all of the sources of the MultiBinding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this needs to be used in conjunction with my answer since the default ValueConverters for the sub-Bindings won't be hit after a MultiConversion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leverage the "default" conversion and use a custom value converter at the same time. So you'd need to implement the "default" conversion in your custom value converter. Something like this leverages the default TypeConverter of the target type:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return System.Convert.ToString(values[0]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        // Get the type of the value, but assume string if it's null
        Type valueType = typeof(string);
        if (value != null)
            valueType = value.GetType();

        // Convert value to the various target types using the default TypeConverter
        object[] values = new object[targetTypes.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
            TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetTypes[i]);
            if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(valueType))
                values[i] = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(value);
            else
                values[i] = value;
        }
        return values;
    }

}
```