# Update Bound Value to item in Dictionary<int, string> or how to Bind to an Attribute of SelectedItem from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a static list of Friendly names for a list of statuses that do not change.  These friendly names (Green, Yellow, Red) correlate to an underylying status value (0, 1, 2..).  For a given item this View will allow the user to select a status from the list and display the description for the status they have selected from the list as it pertains to the item they are currently editing.

The ViewModel exposes the object the user is editing which has a Collection of statuses in a Dictionary.  Selecting a status from the ListBox like Green for example, will display the Text from the Dictionary using the Tag of the Item selected (0 in this case) to display the Value in for that Key ("All is Well" in this case).

I was unable to manually set the Value Attribute for a ListBoxItem so I had to use the Tag.  The model currently works for displaying the text for each status in the collection when Selected Item is changed.  The TextBox uses MultiBinding to the Dictionary Collection and ListBox to display the correct text.

Here is what I have that works:

```
<ListBox Name="StatusItems" Style="{StaticResource MyList}">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Green" Tag="0"></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Yellow" Tag="1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Yellow Audible" Tag="2" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Yellow Flashing" Tag="3" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Yellow Flashing Audible" Tag="4" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Orange" Tag="5" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Audible" Tag="6" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Flashing" Tag="7" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Flashing Audible" Tag="8" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Red" Tag="9" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="RedAudible" Tag="10" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="RedFlashing" Tag="11" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="RedFlashingAudible" Tag="12" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Gray" Tag="13" />
</ListBox>

<TextBox MinLines="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True">
<TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding>
        <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <conv:DictionaryItemConverter />
        </MultiBinding.Converter>
        <Binding Path="Alarm.StatusDescriptions" Mode="TwoWay" />
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Tag" ElementName="StatusItems" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Saveable}"  />
```

Where the model breaks down is when I try to save.  I'm not sure how to persist the changes made to the status back to the correct item in the Dictionary due in part to the MultiValue Converter.  I thought perhaps I could add a SelectedStatus int on the ViewModel and then One-Way Bind the Tag Attribute of the Selected ListBox Item to this property so that when Save was clicked I would know which Key to use to update the description.

I was trying something like this (the syntax is wrong of course)

```
<ListBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedStatus, Mode=OneWayToSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self.SelectedItem.Tag}}" >
```

Can I somehow Bind the Tag Attribute of the SelectedItem to a property on my View?  Or should I scrap the whole idea and go another route?

Comment: There are easier ways to fill a ListBox. Much easier. And in MVVM there are no excuses not to use them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So are we saying I should create some collection to bind the listbox too?  I can do that, its just that the list is a static non changing list of statuses.  Green is just a Friendly name for users, the underlying status description they are editing is for status 0.

And even if I bind it to a different collection it wouldn't be a dictionary and there would be no one-to-one correlation between that lists selected item and the viewmodels dictionary entries.

Comment: I don't mind the down voting, but I would sure appreciate knowning what was wrong so that I might avoid it in the future.

Comment: At the very least you should avoid using Tag. Create a `class { ColorName, Value }`and instantiate a list in ViewModel or XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have your collection of colors that you're binding to the listbox in the ViewModel and another property in the ViewModel to hold the selected color. Something like the below

Your class that holds the color definition

```
public class ColorList
{
    public int ColorCode { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
}
```

And the property definition in the ViewModel

```
private ColorList _selectedColor;
public List<ColorList> AvailableColors
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetColorsList();
    } 
}

public ColorList SelectedColor
{
    get
    {
        return this._selectedColor;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._selectedColor != value)
        {
            this._selectedColor = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedColor");
        }
    }
}
```

The sample method that returns your color list

```
public List<ColorList> GetColorsList()
{
    var result = new List<ColorList> () {
            new ColorList { ColorCode = 0, ColorName = "Green" },
            new ColorList { ColorCode = 1, ColorName = "Yellow" },
            new ColorList { ColorCode = 2, ColorName = "Yellow Audible" }
        };
    return result;
}
```

Finally you can bind the collection to your listbox as follows

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableColor}" DisplayMemberPath="ColorName"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

So now the property `SelectedColor` will have the selected color which you can bind to any other controls.

Comment: I think this may be the way I end up going.  I had been avoiding up until now because I had been considering the idea of colors to really be View specific data.  The colors themselves are meaningless to the underlying services and different applications articulate those statuses in different ways.  In the end I was probably being too strict in my interpetation of keeping the View and View Model seperate.

Answer (score 2):

With WPF, you ideally want your UI separate from your application logic and data.

So your list of items in your ListBox should exist somewhere on the data layer (your ViewModel), and not be an integral part of the UI.

I'm not positive if I'm understanding correctly how your ListBox and Dictionary are linked, however it sounds like you want something like this:

Simplified Model

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string UserDefinedDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Simplified ViewModel

```
public List<SomeObject> Data { get; set; }
public int SelectedDataId { get; set; }
public SomeObject SelectedData 
{
    get { return Data.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == SelectedDataId); }
}
```

Simplified View

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDataId}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    DisplayMemberPath="FriendlyName" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedData.UserDefinedDescription}" />
```

Comment: See, I thought that since the idea of color only existed in the View that the ViewModel should be ignorant of it.  The color "Green" is meanless to the rest of system, it only knows about the underlying status 0.  I had done that because different systems may articulate a status differently or not at all.  I think in the end though I may end up taking your advice and bind ListBox to a Collection on a ViewModel so that I can at least bind to the Selected Value.

Comment: @jrandomuser :) If different systems want to display the data using a different "FriendlyName", then they can update the name on the object model to be whatever they want. The idea is that the functionality will remain the same, regardless of what form of UI is used to display this to the user.

Comment: If you really want to keep the "FriendlyName" out of your object model though, I would recommend using a Converter to convert the `Id` value into whatever string you wish to display. The code would be almost the same as the example I have here, except you'd probably want to implement your own `ListBox.ItemTemplate` which would just be a `TextBlock` with it's `Text` bound to the `Id` property, and using the `IValueConverter` to convert it to whatever UI-appropriate string you want.

Comment: I just wish MultiBinding values were two way back to the source.  The fact that I can get the value just find but can't update it irritates me to no end.

Comment: @jrandomuser I know MultiValueConverters should be two-way, but I'm not sure about MultiBindings. Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5485771/302677) help you at all?

Comment: I did it!  It was the ConvertBack in the MultiValueConverter.  I just needed to return the entire collection instead (which was what I passed in) instead of just the value or even the Key / Value pair.